# Express App: How can I create a setTimeout specific to each user

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

The idea is as follows:

When a user signs up by making a post request to '/signup' I want to create a setTimeout relating to that specific user (the timer needs to be unique). The callback (from the setTimeout) will be responsible for making changes to the user's profile in X minutes. I would also like to store a reference to this timer so that it can be deleted should the user delete their account (/delete route) before X minutes has passed - so the reference to the timer needs to be passable between routes.

Is this possible? If so, how can it be achieved?

Comment: You need to added more details either code or a proper use case for other and I to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see your point，here is a simple idea implement using a global map object.

```
const userTimers = new Map();

app.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
  const user = req.body.user;
  const timer = setTimeout(() => {
    //do some thing
  }, 1000 * 60 * 20);

  // save user's timer, you can use others for key
  userTimers.set(user, timer);

  res.send('success');
});

app.post('/delete', (req, res) => {
  const user = req.body.user;

  if (userTimers.has(user)) {
    const userTimer = userTimers.get(user);
    clearTimeout(userTimer);
    userTimers.delete(user);
  }

  res.send('delete timer');
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('listen on 3000...'));
```

Comment: Quick follow-up question: I guess if the server is restarted for whatever reason; these timers would be lost. How would you go about persisting them to a db? Just a general idea of the logic since the /signup route won't be hit by users after a server restart because they would already have an account - no code needed thank you.

Comment: @mahomed-dev，you're right. After restarting the service, the scheduled task disappears. I think a possible permanent solution is to use Redis with a scheduled cron task.